# Installing PyDev IDE for Eclipse 5.4.0 on Eclipse Mars 4.5.2 throws error "Profile id _SELF_ is not registered"

Tags: eclipse, installation, pydev, eclipse-mars

Problems occurred while performing provisioning operation: Profile id *SELF* is not registered.
Profile id *SELF* is not registered.

Please share your thought on this Thanks

Part of Error Log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.core 2 1 2017-01-07 20:55:23.822
!MESSAGE AERI failed with an error. Please report this error: null ; version: 1.100.0.v20160211-1103
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: The PyDev install page says you need Eclipse 4.6 for PyDev 5.4

Comment: @greg-449 is correct, but just to add more info, there's a section named "Need to use older Eclipse/Java" at http://www.pydev.org/download.html which indicates the proper PyDev version for each eclipse version.

Answer (score 1):

from run go to the %userprofile%   --> C:\users\
go to .p2 folder --- delete all folders/files
run the eclipse .....  close the eclipse ... and start again...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was sufficient to delete the `*.profile.gz` files in

```
C:\Users\%username%\.p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine\profileRegistry\<your profile folder>\
```

(or at least move the files to somewhere else) and restart Eclipse.

I didn't figure out why there seems to be different profile IDs. Maybe because I installed my Eclipse with Oomph, and that was generating some other profile which caused the problem. Just a guess.